# Microsoft Access VBA on open error

Tags: vba, ms-access, compiler-errors

Basically I am populating my form with data from a database. For this I have an onopen event with just this code inside:

```
Me.Requery
```

Everything worked perfectly fine until yesterday, were out of the sudden an error occured. The error states:

> The expression OnOpen you entered as the event property produced the following error: Instruction invalid outside of a type-block.

**Aditional it says in the Discription:**

> - The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure]
> - There may have been an error evaluating the function, event or macro.

When I go to show help it says:

> This error occurs when an event has failed to run because the location of the logic for the event cannot be evaluated. For example, if the OnOpen property of a form is set to =[Field], this error occurs because a macro or event name is expected to run when the event occurs.

However, when I click the message away, everything loaded correctly.

*I am using:*
-Microsoft Access 2013

---

**Q&A:**

Does your code compile successfully?

*Yes, the rest works fine. It also loads everything into the form correctly. But Every time I start it, this info filed pops up.*

**EDIT:** I just noticed that all my on click events throw the same error now.

Could you show the whole code?

*I actually have everything else commented out to troubleshoot the error. If I delete the onopen event the info box disappears.*

Comment: is this Access 365? Normally this is a compilation and not a run-time error. Does your code compile successfuly ? Could you show the whole code?

Comment: Open VBA Editor and under Debug click Compile. Save and reopen. This should fix the issue.

Comment: Omg, thank you, I did find the error. I forgot I had made a few classes of enum type and I did forget to add the access modifier for one variable. Please issue an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have suddenly the same problem, compilation goes fine,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, compilation can fix the problem by finding errors like wrong access modifiers 
When compilation goes fine, one should delete the Form_Load function and let IDE recreate it. This fixed my problem thought apparently no change in code was observed.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks

My problem was naming a label with a Farsi name. After correcting it in English, the problem was solved